# Error when sending Excel file as attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create and save an excel file on server and later send it as a document. At the time of adding attachment, I am getting below error. Anyone have any idea, how can I resolve it ?

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Please find the code which I am using to create excel file and return path, that will be later added as document :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            string attachmentPath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentPath"] as object);
            string path = attachmentPath + FileName;
            excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

            int ColumnIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                ColumnIndex++;
                excel.Cells[1, ColumnIndex] = col.ColumnName;
            }
            int rowIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                rowIndex++;
                ColumnIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    ColumnIndex++;
                    excel.Cells[rowIndex + 1, ColumnIndex] = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                }
            }
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                

            excel.Quit();
            return path + ".xls";
```

Below is the code where I use above path to add as an attachment to the email :

```
            if (attachmentPaths != null && attachmentPaths.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string path in attachmentPaths)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                        message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path));
                }
            }
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(objBO.SmtpDomain);
            smtp.Send(message);
```

Kindly provide suggestions. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question but you don't have the file open in excel or anything by chance do you?

Comment: No. I am creating excel file in code and sending it as attachment the next moment. In the later part I am supposed to delete the same excel file created. So no question of opening it manually meanwhile.

Comment: Your site is probably running under an account with not all permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all of you for your replies. But my problem is solved. Honestly, I don't know the exact reason, but what I did is just added below line after creating/saving excel file on server and before sending email attachment.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is the issue but you never `Close` your Workbook.

```
workbook.Close();
application.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might because you may be opened the excel file from using MS Excel or you are any other programs to read the excel. Check your task manager and close all the applications and re-open the project and try again.

As per the latest comment, while you are doing like this

1. create excel file
2. send excel file
3. delete excel file

I think you are trying to delete a file, which is sending . So  please make sure that you start deleting the file only when the sending is complete.

Sample code

```
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(objBO.SmtpDomain);
        try{
        smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch{
        }
        finally{
         //deletes the file.
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am doing the same thing.
The error I am getting is not while deleting the file, but while adding it as an attachment to the email.
Is there any procedure using which I can close all the processes accessing this file before adding it as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with releasing excel com issues

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9328/Release-Excel-Object

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4 attachments implements IDisposable, so you should make sure you have a using statement so that objects are disposed when out of scope.

```
     if (attachmentPaths != null && attachmentPaths.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string path in attachmentPaths)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                    {
                      using(Attachment data = new Attachment(path))
                       {
                            message.Attachments.Add(data);
                       }
                    }               
                }
            }

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(objBO.SmtpDomain);
smtp.Send(message);
```